# Given a point P and a curve which is defined by discrete points, how to determine point P is near which line between two points

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, statistics

The real problem is about bus, I have some bus GPS data(which I see it as different points), and I know the bus route (which is defined by station points and a series of points between two stations), now for the GPS data, I want to determine the point is between which two adjacent stations. The bus GPS data is collected from bus in its way, the location of data is likely not in the curve of the bus route, instead the location is "near" the curve.

I try to abstract the problem into math description,

let **S** be stations, **S1** means the first station of the bus line, **S2** means the second

let **p** be the points between two stations

Problem description is:

Given **S** and **p**, how to find **i** where a new point **P** is between **Si** and **S(i+1)**

For example: [picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsYnp.png)

In this picture(blue points mean **S**, red points **p** orange points **P**), result should be that point **P** is between **P1** and **P2**

What I have thought about:

Method 1: for lines defined by **Si**, **Si+1**, let **f1=dist(P, Si)+dist(P,Si+1)**, the answer is the line which has min(f1)

Method 2: for lines defined by **Si**, **Si+1**, let dist be the distance between point P to line defined by two points(**Si**, **Si+1**), **f2 = dist(P,Si,Si+1)**, the answer is the line which has min(f2)

Method 3: for lines defined by **Si**, **Si+1**, **p1**, **p2**...**pn**, let **f3=(dist(P,Si)+dist(P,Si+1)+(∑(i=1 to n)(dist(P,pi)))/(n+2)**,the answer is the line which has min(f3)

But these three methods can't solve the problem at all. Any ideas to solve this problem or any advice to describe the problem in a more brief way are appreciated.(I try hard to make my problem clear, but seem to fail)

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_i = ( x_i , y_i )$ for $i = 1 .. N$ be the vertices along the polyline formed by the bus route, and $P = ( x, y )$ be the current location of the bus.

One approach is to pick the polyline segment $\overline{P_i P_{i+1}}$ closest to $P$. This involves finding the distance between *a point and a line segment*, not the distance between a point and a line. (Remember, the latter extends to infinity at both ends.)

I would use the following procedure to find out the distance between $P$ and each line segment:

1. Find the unit vector $U$ from $P_i$ towards $P_{i+1}$, and their distance $d$:
   $$d = \left\lVert P_{i+1} - P_i \right\rVert = \sqrt{ (x_{i+1} - x_i)^2 + (y_{i+1} - y_i)^2} \tag{1}\label{NA1}$$
   $$U = \frac{ P_{i+1} - P_i }{d} = ( x_u , y_u ), \quad \left \lbrace \begin{aligned}
        x_u &= \frac{x_{i+1} - x_i}{d} \\
        y_u &= \frac{y_{i+1} - y_i}{d} \end{aligned} \right . \tag{2}\label{NA2}$$
2. Parametrise the line as
   $$L(t) = P_i + t U = ( x_L , y_L )$$
   $$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
        x_L(t) &= x_i + t x_u \\
        y_L(t) &= y_i + t y_u
      \end{aligned} \right .$$
   The important point is to note that $L(0) = P_i$, and $L(d) = P_{i+1}$; i.e. $0 \le t \le d$, for $L(t)$ to be a point on the line segment.
3. Find the point $L(t)$ closest to $P$.

   When the line through $L(t)$ and $P$ is perpendicular to the unit vector $U$ (or any line through $P_i$ and $P_{i+1}$), then $L(t)$ is the closest point to $P$ on the line, and their dot product is zero:
   $$\left ( L(t) - P \right ) \cdot U = 0$$
   i.e.
   $$( x_L(t) - x ) x_u + ( y_L(t) - y ) y_u = 0$$
   and substituting $x_L(t)$ and $y_L(t)$ we get
   $$( x_i + t x_u - x ) x_u + ( y_i + t y_u - y ) y_u = 0$$
   and solving for t, noting that $x_u^2 + y_u^2 = 1$, we get
   $$t = (x - x_i) x_u + (y - y_i) y_u \tag{3}\label{NA3}$$
4. Calculate the distance $r$ at that point.

   We can use either
   $$r = \sqrt{ (x_i + t x_u - x)^2 + (y_i + t y_u - y)^2 } \tag{4a}\label{NA4a}$$
   or
   $$r = \left\lvert x_u ( y - y_i ) - y_u ( x - x_i ) \right\rvert \tag{4b}\label{NA4b}$$
   as they are equivalent (when $\eqref{NA3}$ is true and $x_u^2 + y_u^2 = 1$). I recommend using the latter in computer programs, as taking the absolute value is much faster than taking a square root.
5. Determine the distance $R$ between point $P$ and line segment $\overline{P_i P_{i+1}}$:
   $$R = \begin{cases}
          r, & 0 \le t \le d \\
          \sqrt{(x_i - x)^2 + (y_i - y)^2}, & t < 0 \\
          \sqrt{(x_{i+1} - x)^2 + (y_{i+1} - y)^2}, & t > d
      \end{cases} \tag{5}\label{NA5}$$
   The first case occurs when $L(t)$ is on the line segment, so we use the distance from $P$ to the line.
   The second case occurs when $L(t)$ is on the line, before $P_i$.
   The third case occurs when $L(t)$ is on the line, after $P_{i+1}$.

Point $P$ is "on" the polyline segment that minimizes $R$, so you need to calculate it for each line segment, and pick the segment with smallest $R$.

Note that the above method may not be sufficient when the bus $P$ is close to some station $P_k$, because $P$ may be closer to the station than to the line from that station to the next. So, in the case where station $P_k$ is closest to $P$, you cannot tell whether $P$ is between $P_{k-1}$ and $P_k$, or between $P_k$ and $P_{k+1}$. You'd need to remember bus state, whether the last few measurements indicated distance to $P_k$ was increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I can feel that your method is more appropriate, but I can't tell why this is better. And how to know which method fit the problem best? I have an idea that try these methods and compare the result with a correct set, and see the accuracy. But how can I make a correct set for test?(how to generate datas?)

Comment: With the help of your answer, I found that I make the issue complicate myself . I think station point is different from the point in between, and try hard to find a value which combine all the segments between two station points. But what I need to care is still a problem of a new point and the segment line between two other points. There is no need to distinguish station points and other points.(This can be easily get when I find the small segment line)

Comment: @Marbo: What I'd do, is use a large number of samples, perhaps at something like 50m or 100m resolution, and when getting a GPS reading, simply find the closest sample. This is not a problem even if you had millions of samples; there are fast techniques for this. To generate the samples, I'd ride the bus, with a GPS tracker (that lets you save the coordinates to a file), the same route at least a couple of times. You might have a smartphone that can do that.

Comment: It seems that I comment too much, this comment is for your GPS tracker comment. Yes, I know that I can get GPS data somehow, but I don't know how to get the "correct answer" for comparing purpose. Do I need to label the result manually?(Can't be yes) What techniques do you mean?

Comment: I can't quiet understand (5), Let X be the projection point, why R be set to max(distance(p1,X),r) when X on the line segment where p1 is the endpoint. Why this way than other? For example, set R be max(dist(P, endPoint), r) can also be a choice. It seems that there can be many different settings. How to measure one better than another?

Comment: @Marbo: Re GPS, the device needs to collect the data points in *time order*, and preferably once every second or even more often, so you can filter and decimate the set (to a smaller set, with data points at regular intervals).

Comment: @Marbo: As to point 5, I modified it to yield a better result. When the point closest to $P$ is within the endpoints ($0 \le t \le d$), we use the distance between $P$ and the line as $R$. Otherwise, we use the distance to the *endpoint* instead.

Comment: Re point 5: the R defined in your answer and in your comment are not same. How to know which R is better?

Comment: @Marbo: They do match, I just forgot to edit the explanation of the first $R$ case in the answer to match the edited form. The first case is when the point $L(t)$ closest to $P$ is between the current line endpoints. The second case is when the point is before the first endpoint, so the distance from $P$ to the line segment is the distance from $P$ to the first endpoint $P_i$. The third case is when $P$ is closest to a point after the line segment, and therefore closest to $P_{i+1}$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t notice that you have modified your answer.